# Ошибка при вызове self.puts в Ruby

Tags: ruby

Всем доброго дня!

Начал изучать ruby по книге Криса Пайна "Учись программировать".
Так вот. Там есть вот такой пример:

```
iCantBelieveIMadeAVariableNameThisLongJustToPointToA3 = 3
puts iCantBelieveIMadeAVariableNameThisLongJustToPointToA3
self.puts iCantBelieveIMadeAVariableNameThisLongJustToPointToA3
```

который по словам автора должен вернуть:

```
3
3
```

Но в ответ на вызов self.puts я получаю:

```
3
ex3.rb:8:in '<main>': private method 'puts' called for main:Object <NoMethodError>
```

Кто-нибудь может по возможности максимально детально объяснить, почему такая конструкция не работает (а также почему работала ранее, если работала)?
И почему работает такая:

```
iCantBelieveIMadeAVariableNameThisLongJustToPointToA3 = 3
puts iCantBelieveIMadeAVariableNameThisLongJustToPointToA3
self.send(:puts, iCantBelieveIMadeAVariableNameThisLongJustToPointToA3)
```

Заранее огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: @vladchernik, очеидно, что puts объявлен как private, поэтому его может вызвать только текущий класс. send же - публичный метод, однако он выполняется в контексте класса, поэтому имеет доступ к приватным методам.

Comment: @Etki, выходит, что puts объявлен как private по умолчанию? Так, что ли? И даже если так, то почему я не могу его вызвать в данной ситуации? Текущий класс = ?

p.s. написанные три строчки - это всё содержимое файла.

Спасибо.

Comment: @vladchernik, честно говоря, я не рубист, и мне не очень понятно, на что здесь указывает self. На stackoverflow я натыкался на фразу "puts can't have a receiver", под которым, очевидно, подразумевается self.

Comment: @Etki, в любом случае спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @pirj, большое спасибо за то, что разжевали!  
Только один вопрос остался: в ранних версиях это можно было сделать (выполнить такую конструкцию)? Или в книге ложная информация?

P.S. Еще, подскажите, пожалуйста, как выбрать ваш комментарий ответом? Или для этого нужно определенное количество "репутации"?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@vladchernik](/users/15474/vladchernik)](/users/15474/vladchernik), `puts` объявлен в `Kernel` как `private`. Вы можете вызывать его, но явно использовать контекст (`self.`), как это можно делать с `protected`, нельзя. Текущий класс = `main`.